# bind attribute within a component leaking to other components in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that I load multiple times in a page. And I am binding class to one of the elements in the component based on a property of the component.
A simple example that demonstrates the issue is here : http://jsbin.com/iKabiKi/1/

You can see in the example that if I click on one of the links, the class is changed to all the other component elements!

I am not sure if I am doing things wrong or if this is a bug. Your insight will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are initiated and live on the class, not the instance.  Initialize it during init, or somewhere else to avoid this issue.

http://jsbin.com/iKabiKi/2/edit